# Attaching Xen PV Drivers to Windows Boot Manager

Tags: windows, wdk, xen, winpe, bcdedit

On a vm I have two drives each with Windows 10. As this is inside of a XEN HVM instance, the Windows Boot Manager can only launch Windows on the first drive (I'd like to be able to launch Windows on the 2nd drive). Once the system boots on Drive 1, Windows has the XEN PV Drivers to see that other drive in the Disk Manager. If I use BCDEdit to create a new entry for the D: drive, it'll appear that it was added successfully. But, when rebooting, The Boot Manager will always say the drive doesn't exist.

My guess is I need to get the boot manager to somehow load the PV Drivers before trying to load the OS on the 2nd drive. Question is: how? Is there a way to add drivers using BCDEdit? Another tool?

Comment: Is the second drive connected in the same way as the first (are all the settings in the Xen config the same other than paths to the volume & drive letter)? I would have thought that the bootloader would be able to see both drives as long as they are both using the QEMU emulation at that point. Are you able to make the same changes on a physical box and everything works as expected?

Comment: this is actually on EC2. they only expose the first drive to BIOS -- even if there are attached SSD. this is why i need to load the PV drivers first.